# Why null pointer exception was giving in jQuary section please give me brief explanation

Tags: java, mysql, spring, error-handling, runtime-error

this is the problem while I am hitting api it will give this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.JdbcMapping.getJdbcValueBinder()" because "jdbcMapping" is null
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.AbstractJdbcParameter.bindParameterValue(AbstractJdbcParameter.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.AbstractJdbcParameter.bindParameterValue(AbstractJdbcParameter.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.bindParameters(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:199) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.getMetaData(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.getColumnCount(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.results.ResultSetMappingImpl.resolve(ResultSetMappingImpl.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.resolveJdbcValuesSource(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:477) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]




@GetMapping("/get_product_by_category_and_price_greater_than")
List<Product>products  
@Query(value = "select p from Product p where p.price >= :price and p.catagory = :catagory", nativeQuery = true)
```

I expect a product list from which price is greater then given price

Comment: honestly, if this is your code, I'm surprised it compiles

Comment: The exception message tells you that the field (or variable) `jdbcMapping` is null - most probably because you never initialize it (or because you didn't configure your beans correctly)